# Open rdp:// Link from Browser in Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: desktop, remote-control, microsoft

I was wondering if there's any chance to open rdp://host.ip.address links from my browser (Safari, Firefox, ..) in Microsoft Remote Desktop (MacOS Version)?

Is there any script or command something similar to:
https://github.com/richard-green/MstscLauncher

Thanks a lot and stay healthy.

Comment: In Firefox, I *think so.* In Firefox preferences, under applications (if you have already downloaded an .rdp file) there should be an entry for said files. You just have to select the default action. Mine is set to "Ask" but there was an option to open them in MS Remote Desktop. Conversely I didn't see that option in Safari so you may *have* to use Firefox. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for your tip.
I created a "remote.rdp" file with e.g. "full address:s:192.123.123.123" and set the file action in Firefox (works on Linux Mint + Remmina).

But in my case it's not a link to a .rdp file, it's a link like "rdp://$HOSTADDRESS$" (wildcard, CheckMK icon btw).
In Windows I could define the action by the MstscLauncher from above. 
Now I'm looking for a rule in MacOS and Linux (Mint). That would be perfect.

Comment: We have a lot of people working from home and accessing our RDP server from a web browser. Oddly enough Google Chrome seems to automatically open those RDP files. I would imagine that behavior can be changed in Chrome's settings, but I avoid Chrome if I can, so no experience there. And for Safari, you may have to look for tools that change default settings (Onyx springs to mind) as Safari seems to not have those settings exposed to us poor dumb users...

Comment: It's not a .rdp file. It's a link called "rdp://HOST" - no link to a file! That's my question.